# Function that count the same values in specify column in data frame

Tags: sql, r

As in the topic, what function will count how many rows consist the same value in chosen column and add new column with this values?

If it helps, I just want to rewrite this SQL code:

```
COUNT(*) AS NumLinks FROM PostLinks GROUP BY RelatedPostId
```

But in R base functions.

Comment: Youu can use `table` `table(PostLinks$RelatedPostId)` in `base R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `table` from `base R`

```
table(PostLinks$RelatedPostId)
```

Or if we need to create a new column in `base R`

```
PostLinks$Count <- with(PostLinks, ave(seq_along(RelatedPostID),
          RelatedPostId, FUN = length))
```

---

If we need to add a new column, use `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)    
PostLinks2 <- PostLinks %>%
                 add_count(RelatedPostId)
```

Comment: @Aleksandra if you need a new column, use the `add_count`, updated the post

Comment: @Aleksandra you can use `ave`, updated or with `rep`  assuming the data is ordered i.e. `tbl <- table(PostLinks$RelatedPostId); rep(tbl, tbl)`

Comment: @Aleksandra no problem. have a great weekend1